# Unity - Prefab Spawn Point

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am creating a player *Prefab* that should spawn if the player connects to the server.

I have been testing the *Prefabs*, and it is spawning but not in the position i want.

Can someone help me to fix my problem?

Here is my position-point function:

```
public class PointJSON
{
    public float[] position;
    public PointJSON(SpawnPoint spawnPoint)
    {
        //* Position 
        position = new float[]
        {
            spawnPoint.transform.position.x,
            spawnPoint.transform.position.y,
         };
    }
}
```

And here is my instantiated `GameObject`:

```
userJSON currentUserJSON = userJSON.CreateFromJSON(data);
Vector2 position = new Vector2(currentUserJSON.position[0],currentUserJSON.position[1]);
GameObject p = Instantiate(player, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do spawner where this player can be respawn if he connects with server.

Here you have sample of my code where mobs respawn at a certain time:

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] chickens;
    public Vector3 spawnValues;
    public float spawnWait;
    public float spawnMostWait;
    public float spawnLeastWait;
    public int startWait;
    public bool stop;

    int randEnemy;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(waitSpawner());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        spawnWait = Random.Range(spawnLeastWait, spawnMostWait);
    }

    IEnumerator waitSpawner()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);

        while (!stop)
        {
            randEnemy = Random.Range(0, 2);
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), Random.Range(-spawnValues.y, spawnValues.y), -3);
            Instantiate(chickens[randEnemy], spawnPosition + transform.TransformPoint(0, 0, 0), gameObject.transform.rotation);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);
        }
    }   
}
```

I put spawner (like a block) on the game project and set this script to the block.
There I choose which object can respawn, size of object, how many mobs alive (for example you can see 10 mobs on the map not more from this spawner) can respawn and coordinates to spawn.
Maybe this example help you something or will bring another idea to solver your problem.

Good Luck